# How to increase the height of the react-native Slider component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a react native project... one of my cases I need to use Slider component in react-native.

```
<Slider 
  minimumTrackTintColor='blue'
  maximumTrackTintColor='red'
  width={300}
  value={16}
  minimumValue ={0}
  maximumValue={100}
/>
```

I can control the width of the Slider component but I need to increase the height of the Slider. Are any suggestions there?

Comment: can you tell us what component you used in the project?

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
style={{height:300}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the [official documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/slider.html):

[image: Print screen taken from the official React Native librarie site]

- **Following the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-slider) for the new component, try using this:**

  > style={{height: 40}}

  ```
  <Slider
      style={{width: 200, height: 40}}
  />
  ```